# What is the thread and size of a Chevy Malibu 2009 Hybrid with ATC blower module retaining bolt size?

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, heater-blower, bolts, control

I was wondering if any of you guys could possibly know the thread of the retaining bolts of the blower module (ATC) to a Chevy Malibu 2009. Thanks advancely !

Comment: Since you have not gotten an answer here, you may want to ask a Chevrolet dealership.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the size is 4.2-1.41 x 20mm 7mm Indented Hex Head

Comment: Actually I called the dealership, they just wanted to sell the brand new module, they don't even sell the bolts apart, and the guy said they only have part numbers so he couldn't tell the size.